# warning: returning ‘float (*)[3]’ from a function with incompatible return type ‘float *’

Tags: arrays, c, compiler-warnings

I am getting the error 'warning: returning ‘float (*)[3]’ from a function with incompatible return type ‘float *’' when I'm trying to return an array in a function. I've read C has problems with returning arrays but don't really understand why and what to do to fix it. This is my code:

```
float * buildlocs(int L, int W, int H){
int c = 0, xmin, xmax, x, ymin, ymax, y, h;
unsigned int nX, nY;
L = L/4;
W = W/4;
float cellarray[16][3];


for(nX = 0; nX < 4;nX++) {
    for(nY = 0; nY < 4;nY++) {
        xmin = 0+L*(nX-1);
        xmax = L*nX;
        x = xmin+rand()*(xmax-xmin);
        
        ymin = 0+W*(nY-1);
        ymax = W*nY;
        y = ymin+rand()*(ymax-ymin);
        
        h = rand()*H;

        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            if(i == 0){
                cellarray[c][i] = x;                     
            }
            if(i == 1){
                cellarray[c][i] = y;  
            }
            if(i == 2){
                cellarray[c][i] = h;
            }

        }

        c = c + 1;
    }
}

return cellarray;
}
```

The goal is to have an 2d array with 16 entries which contain 3 variables. Could someone please help me fix the error?

Comment: a `float[16][3]` is obviously not a `float*`.
This is undefined behaviour because you return a local array. That array ceases to exist after the function returns.
You need to transfer the data in another way to the caller. For example via dynamic allocation or passing a pointer to the function to an already allocated array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems:

First, a `float[16][3]` is *not* a `float*`.
Second, `float cellArray[16][3]` ceases to exist at the end of the function - it is a local variable that only exists in that function. when you return the address of the array, the pointer will point to something non existing - a so-called *dangling pointer*.

To solve the issue, you need to allocate the array either dynamically and return the pointer to the dynamically allocated array like this (dont forget to `free` when you are done with `cellArray`):

```
float* cellArray = malloc(sizeof(float)*16*3); // this is one contiguous block of floats, you have to figure out how you want to index into this block, since it's stricly speaking not a two dimensional array.
//...//
return cellArray;
```

OR, what i find more elegant is, passing a pointer to an already existing array:

```
void buildlocs(float* outLocs, int L, int W, int H); // added parameter to take a float*

//in your function that calls buildlocs:

float[16][3] cellArray;
buildlocs(&cellArray[0],L,W,H); // pass allocated array into function, again, this is a pointer, not a two-dimensional array
```

Comment: I kinda get it, but what does the line: float[16][3] cellArray; create exactly?

Comment: It is an uninitialized array on the automatic storage (stack).
It will cease to exist once that function returns, but you can pass it around into functions as long as it exists.